# I get a NameError: uninitialized constant CoffeeScript::ExecJS on a Rails 4 app deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I have a Rails 4 app deployed on my Digital Ocean LAM-Rails VPS. I have been developing it for quite a while and all has been going well but now when I want to run a migration or clean assets I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CoffeeScript::ExecJS
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/coffee-script-2.3.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:5:in `<module:CoffeeScript>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/coffee-script-2.3.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/coffee-script-2.3.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/coffee-script-2.3.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/var/www/html/kosarka/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/kosarka/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/var/www/html/kosarka/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My Gem file looks the following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
    gem 'mysql2'
    gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
    gem 'execjs'
end

#To validate delivery date is in the futurebund
gem 'date_validator'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
# Use Paperclip for image upload
gem 'paperclip'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# For development on Windows machines
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

I develop this app both on a Win7 machine and a Mac and I have no problem running it in the dev environments.

I use Phusion Passenger on the server and usually just pulled the repo content with a .sh script and ran the rake migrate asset clean and precompile commands.

Any help would be much appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this section:

```
group :production do
    gem 'mysql2'
    gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
    gem 'execjs'
end
```

to

```
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'execjs'
```

P.S. I think your application will be works fine without `execjs` gem too. Try to check it for any case.

Comment: I don't see the relevance as I only use mysql2 and the rest in production and I have no problem with my application in development environment. It seems the problem was a bundle update that updated all the relevant gems and messed up the things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be a rather clouded answer. I have seen this question coming up from many on stackOverflow but the tips (rm -rf .bundle and cache etc.) did not help me.

So I just reverted back to an old Gem file and Gem.lock and it happened to solve the problem.

Then I went to Bitbucket and had a look on the commit and figured out actually it was all the version changes in the *Gem.lock* (probably an accidental bundle update instead of bundle install) that might caused the problem.

Eventhough in my Gemfile there was only a date_validator change, my Gem.lock was full of new versions of the following:

```
bcrypt
capistrano
coffee-script-source
execjs
multi_json
jbuilder
spring
```

I still could not get to the depth of the problem but at least figured how to avoid it.